# while( scanf("%d", &n) ) { ... } not exit when press Ctrl+D on Linux

Tags: c++, c, scanf

If using this code to read an `int` number, when I press Ctrl + D, this program won't exit.

```
while( scanf("%d", &n) ) { ... }
```

But if I use this, it will exit.

```
while( scanf("%d", &n) == 1 ) { ... }
```

The OS I test this code is Linux and the compiler is g++ 7.3.1.

Comment: Ctrl+D would return `EOF` which is non-zero. Thus the loop continues. You are expecting to read one element, so your latter fix (comparing with 1) is the correct way to proceed.

Comment: What makes you think it should exit the loop on Ctrl-D?

Comment: @alk I think that the return value of `scanf` is the number of successful read variable, so when I press Ctrl + D, the return value is zero. After reading the comments and answers under this question, it seems that what I think is wrong. :)

Comment: Reading the documentation mostly ever helps: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html

Comment: "*The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before
       either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.*" So take care, `EOF` might even indicate invalid input.

Comment: Obligatory: prefer reading entire lines (with `fgets` for example, or `getline` if available), then parsing them (with `sscanf` for example). Use input is submitted when enter is pressed, so it's best to handle it that way too.

Comment: I don't know why everybody repeats the mantra about not using scanf, and I disagree with it. scanf is a very powerful tool, and if you learn how to use it, it works great and can do astonishing feats. It is like every tool, if you don't know how to use it correctly, it might go wrong.

Comment: @Aganju Because interactive reading from stdin is line based, and often has mistakes. Working with these two requirements using `scanf` is complicated and error prone. You need to read entire line of user input *anyway* because that is what operating system and standard library give you, so it's simplest to do it a first step.

Comment: @Aganju @hyde Hey, thanks for your suggestions, both. But I don't know much about C in software engineering. Actually, I mostly use Python. I just use it to solve ACM problems in online judge. I hear that `scanf` is faster than `cin` and the time limitation is very important in those problems, so I use this function. :)

Comment: @callofdutyops I would think the time limitation is for algorithmic complexity. Using `cin` or `scanf` is not going to make any difference what so ever, unless you are reading gigabytes of data (which you aren't on any online problems).

Comment: @hyde Yes, you're right, the data in online judge usually is small, but the time limit is also small, such as 1 second. And I have encountered the situation that using `cin` cause `time limit exceeded` but `scanf` `accepted`. I think this may because my algorithm is not very efficient, so this tiny time difference result in different result.

Comment: @Aganju *I don't know why everybody repeats the mantra about not using scanf, and I disagree with it. scanf is a very powerful tool, and if you learn how to use it* for the same reason that you don't use the screw driver for nailing a nail. `scanf` **is** a power full for scanning **formatted** input, it was **not** design to read user input from stdin which is not formatted, is random. `scanf` is just not the right tool to read human input from `stdin`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first code you wrote:

```
while( scanf("%d", &n) ) { ... }
```

would work fine *if* `scanf` returned true for success and false for failure.  But that's not what `scanf` returns.

`scanf` actually returns the number of items successfully matched.  Or it returns 0 if none were matched.  Or (and this is the key point) it returns the negative value `EOF` (typically -1) if end-of-file is reached, for example when you typed control-D.

The first code you wrote loops as long as `scanf` returns nonzero.  That's why it looped forever.

The second code you wrote:

```
while( scanf("%d", &n) == 1 ) { ... }
```

loops as long as `scanf` successfully matches the one item it asked you to.  That's the correct way to do it, and that's why it worked.

Comment: The key point you point out is very important! Thanks for your clear answer!

Answer (score 0):

After the first read, `scanf` fetch the buffer content. That's why you get a endless loop. Its then irrelevant what you type.